# Handling a large resource file in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

My javascript app has a class Dictionary. The dictionary reads a large json (require..) file.

I have a bunch of questions regarding best practices.

1. I would like to load the Dictionary once, while the Splashcreen is shown. I am using react navigation v5. How to achieve that?
2. How do I assure, that the dictionary exists only on time in memory (not multiple versions, anytime the parent component is rendered)

Comment: How big is your file in MB's?

Comment: it is about 10MB